# Vmware Workstation: connect guest VM to host VM and the rest ot the network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to use Vmware Workstation as a server for a dev/test machine and share the VM.
Have set the guest VM interface to bridged.
Host has two interfaces: wired and wireless.
Other network machine that must access the VM has just one: wired.

Guest VM can ping both wired interfaces on host and network machine.
Guest VM can not ping wireless interface: `Destination host unreachable`

Both host and network machine can not ping the guest: `Request timed out`

It does not make any sense to me. Any ideas?